# How do I move only coming occurences of a series in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, time

I have created a series that occurs every week. Now I want to change the time of this series. When doing this Outlook changes the time also for past events. I do not want this. What can I do? I came up with the idea of limiting the "Range of recurrence" to today. But when I want to do this, Outlook warns me "Any exceptions associated with this recurring appointment will be cancelled."
This is not OK for me. What can I do?